# How to reduce the area around a highcart?

Tags: highcharts

I have a highchart scatter chart that's set to 37px height and 125px width.  With those dimensions, the actual chart size is much smaller because of the background.  Is there a way to make the chart fill the entire content area with no background?

Here's a chart with a similar setup.

http://jsfiddle.net/6Ljrk87o/2/

```
{
    inverted: true,
    type: 'scatter'
},
margin: [0, 0, 0, 0],
title: {
    text: null
},
```

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: You seem to have misplaced the `margin`. It seems to be in the root, rather than `chart.margin`. Does this fix the problem?

Comment: @HalvorStrand is right, just move the `margin` inside `chart` [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6Ljrk87o/10/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To reduce the area around Highcharts chart decrease spacing.

```
chart: {
  spacing: [0, 0, 0, 0]
}
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/5p1k4d2h/

API Reference: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.spacing